# Add project dll which contains a service reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, soap, service-reference

I have a dll which contains a service reference (SOAP). I want to load that dll on another project, like normal dlls but this doesn't work. I get this little yellow triangle ([References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38XuL.png))

When I reference "normal" dlls I don't have problems. I work with Visual Studio 2015 and the programming language is C#.

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to .Net version mismatch. Check the dll's target .Net framework version.

Comment: Ok that was a simple answer which helps! Thank you!!